# WebFlux always get empty body posting from WebClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to post Flux from webclient to server and I always get empty request body.

Router:

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> procces(LetterHandler handler){
        return RouterFunctions.route(POST("/letter").and(accept(APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)).and(contentType(APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)), handler::handle);
    }
```

Handler method:

```
@Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> handle(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        serverRequest.body(toFlux(Letter.class)).doOnEach(letterSignal -> System.out.println(letterSignal)).switchIfEmpty(subscriber -> System.out.println("empty")).subscribe();
        //serverRequest.bodyToFlux(Letter.class).doOnEach(letterSignal -> System.out.println(letterSignal)).subscribe();
}
```

WebClient -field:

```
private final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8081")
           // .defaultHeader(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
```

WebClient - request:

```
public void send(Flux letters) {

    webClient.post().uri("/letter")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .body(letters, Letter.class)
            //.body(BodyInserters.fromObject(letter))
           // .retrieve().bodyToMono(void.class).subscribe();
            .exchange().subscribe();
}
```

Why do I always get empty request? I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: isn't your `handle` method incomplete? what is the returned `Mono<ServerResponse>`?